# Visual Studio error LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm having problems with Visual Studio. Even though the code worked earlier, I keep getting this error now:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Lab3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Q3.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in Q1.obj
1>C:\Users\Carlos\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Lab3\Debug\Lab3.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two files (`Q1` and `Q3`) that both define `main`. You can only define `main` once in the entire project.

Comment: Thanks, so I removed Main() from one of them and this is wat I get when i try to run it now,

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: Lab3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  lab3_3.c
1>c:\users\carlos\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab3\lab3\lab3_3.c(5): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\users\carlos\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab3\lab3\lab3_3.c(20): error C2059: syntax error : '}'

Comment: @user3291588: It sounds like you removed the `main()` part, but left the body of the function there. You need to remove the whole function.

Comment: yea I did removed the main(), how do I make it so they'll both work?

Comment: Remove "main() { ...Some codes Here... }" from your lab3_3.c file. That means remove the whole main() function.